# Document Library - Edit in browser

Tags: document-library

I have document library which has three folder and sub-folders inside on it.
When I tried access a excel file, in two folders I have an option to "Edit in Browser". But for one folder that option was not there for that user. I have provided same access level for that users in all the folders.

Could any on please help on this.

Thanks in advance

Thanks,

Comment: Are the files all XLSX format? Older XLS format cannot be edited in browser.

Comment: Thanks Kim. But I am able to do edit in browser as site admin access.

Comment: But not in contribute access. Particularly for that folder.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following link will help you  :
    https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Excel-Web-App-in-a-SharePoint-library-53f7d410-65bc-49a9-ac47-6d99d45a1d57